# Control specularity of texture in compositor

Tags: lighting

I made a specular texture, and I'd like to have a lamp off to the side that helps it sparkle more. I'm trying to figure out how to get a lamp node to effect this texture only, but I'm very lost.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

figured it out. mix a lamp node with a texture, plug the mix into the spec of a copy of the material, then mix the two materials together.

[image]